# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Rows' of Object_Global failed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am writing VBA code for finding last_row of next sheet inside a chart sheet, in chart I a using Chart_MouseUp and Chart_MouseDown function here I am explaining Chart_MouseUp  inside  Chart_MouseDown event I am taking I am taking chart start point x and y co-ordinate and and on Chart_MouseUp  event I am taking chart end point x and y co-ordinate and after this process I am storing start point and end end point x co-ordinate inside next sheet "AQ" column for this purpose I have to know number of cell which is blanked inside AQ column for this I have to know last_Row of AQ cell and for this purpose I am using this code

```
           Dim last_Row As Integer
           last_Row = Sheets(5).Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
           MsgBox last_Row
```

**Run-time error '1004'
 Method 'Rows'  of Object_Global failed**

Whenever code like

```
'Sheets(5).Range("AQ4") = startX
'Sheets(5).Range("AQ5") = endX
```

is working inside same sheet
here is Chart_MouseUp event code Please if you have an Idea to handle this problem then guide me

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, _
        ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

    Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
    Dim myX As Variant, myY As Double
  With ActiveChart
        ' Pass x & y, return ElementID and Args
        .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2
        ' Did we click over a point or data label?
        If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
            If Arg2 > 0 Then
                ' Extract x value from array of x values
                myX = WorksheetFunction.Index _
                    (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
                ' Extract y value from array of y values
                myY = WorksheetFunction.Index _
                    (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
                     endX = CDate(myX)
                     endY = myY
                   ' Display message box with point information
                     MsgBox "X = " & startX & vbCrLf _
                    & "Y = " & startY & vbCrLf _
                    & "X = " & endX & vbCrLf _
                    & "Y = " & endY
                    'Sheets(5).Range("AQ4") = startX
                    'Sheets(5).Range("AQ5") = endX
                    Dim last_Row As Integer
                    'Dim sh As Worksheet
                    last_Row = Sheets(5).Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
                    MsgBox last_Row

            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

Your problem is not entirely clear, but the issue seems to be that you are receiving the 1004 error at this line in your code: `last_Row = Sheets(5).Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`.

If that's the case, and assuming that your chart is a "Chart Sheet" (i.e. a separate Worksheet that contains only a Chart), and not a Chart that is simply embedded in a "Standard Sheet" (i.e. a Worksheet that contains rows and columns), then that error would be expected.

The reason for this is that the `Rows` object is not available when the Active Sheet is a "Chart Sheet", because such a sheet does not contain any rows (or columns). Clearly, that "Chart Sheet" is indeed the Active Sheet while your code is running, because your code runs at the firing of the Chart's `Mouse_Up` event.

**Resolution:**

The resolution for this issue is simple. Assuming that `Worksheets(5)` is a sheet that does contain rows and columns, replace the problem line of code with this one:

```
last_Row = Sheets(5).Range("B" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Or, a better alternative may be to replace the problem line with these instead:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5)
last_Row = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

**Note:**

Your code is using four variables that have not been declared (two of which have not even been assigned a value). This is not related to the 1004 error, but it is good coding practice to declare variables before they are used.

To help avoid this issue in the future, you can include an `Option Explicit` statement at the top of your Module, which will force all variables in that Module to be declared. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855(v=office.14).aspx).

To do this automatically for every new Module that is created, enable this option in the VBA Editor: Tools -> Options -> [Editor Tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264092(v=office.14).aspx) -> Require Variable Declaration

Comment: Hey MJH it is not complete code my complete code is on my blog here     http://synapsetechno.blogspot.com/2016/12/method-rows-of-Object-Global-failed.html

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're trying to get at there. If my answer [resolved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (and, once you have sufficient reputation, you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) helpful answers as well). Otherwise, please explain how and/or why the answer is not working for you.